# php regix patern check

Tags: php, regex, function, if-statement

i need a regular expression for check two string and return data

```
$str = "/mypage/20/my-slug";
$subject = "/mypage/{id}/{slug}";
$pattern = ''; 
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

need this array

```
array(
    'id'=>20,
    'slug'=>'my-slug',
    ...
)
```

Comment: Have you even tried searching for it? Just copy/pasting your title into google (even with the spelling errors) will give you multiple correct examples and answers.

Comment: for this patern `/mypage/{id}` not find any.

Comment: First learn how to user regex in PHP (which you find if you just search), then read some guides about regex-patterns. This question shows no effort or attempts to solve the issue yourself. We'll gladly help you if you run into some specific issue with your existing code, but that means you need to actually try something yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you have your function:

```
<?php

$str = "/mypage/20/my-slug";
$subject = "/mypage/{id}/{slug}";

function getQueryParameters($url, $pattern)
{
    // Find first parameter:
    $pos=strpos($pattern, '{');

    if($pos===false)
    {
        return [];
    }

    $prefix=substr($pattern, 0, $pos);

    // Check for route
    if(substr($url, 0, $pos)!=$prefix)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $curlyBracesRegex='/'
        . '\{'              // One {
        . '([^\s}]+)'       // something inside curly braces, e.g. {foo}
                            // Excluding whitespaces (\s)
        . '\}'              // One }
        . '/';

    preg_match_all($curlyBracesRegex, $pattern, $matches);

    $parameters=[];
    foreach ($matches[0] as $index => $match)
    {
        $parameters[]=$matches[1][$index];
    }

    $matches=explode('/', substr($url, $pos));

    $queryParameters=array_combine($parameters, $matches);

    return $queryParameters;
}

print_r(getQueryParameters($str, $subject));
```

You can test here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8646e13bfc5a2b9ed5e2a5a2a9b9ddf1b0ab9db5

Answer (score 0):

You can try like code:

```
$subject = "www.example.com?id=10&name=johnny";
$pattern = '/id=[0-9A-Za-z]*/'; //$pattern = '/id=[0-9]*/'; if it is only numeric.
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: i need `/mypage/{id}` for check pattern